# Magento - Unable to set order of collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sorting

This doesn't seem to be ordered correctly, anything I'm doing wrong?  Suggestions?

```
$componentQuantityCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$componentQuantityCollection->joinField('qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left');
$componentQuantityCollection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $componentSkus))->setOrder('sku','ASC');
```

Another collection that doesn't seem to be sorted which is different than the first:

```
$kitCollection = Mage::getModel('kitinventory/kitinventory')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('kit_sku', $sku)->setOrder('related_sku', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

EAV collections work with attributes, the sorting method is a little different here as well

```
$componentQuantityCollection->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'ASC');
```

For non-EAV collections use one of the following methods

```
$kitCollection->getSelect()->order('related_sku DESC');
$kitCollection->setOrder('related_sku', 'DESC');
```

Comment: what about the second collection?

Comment: That's a flat type collection, so no EAV and attributes. Take a look at this answer on how to sort that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11354060

Comment: I tried setOrder('related_sku','DESC'); but it's not sorted.

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: Ah, gracious -- still unsure why you can't just chain them in a similar manner.

Comment: The non-EAV approach worked for me. Although, in my case it wasn't working because addAttributeToSort() was adding an IF statement with back ticks all over the place. In result, MySQL kept throwing an error. Thanks.

Comment: @easymoden00b use this `$kitCollection->getSelect()->order('related_sku DESC');`

Answer (score 15):

You can add sort order like this:

```
$kitCollection->getSelect()->order('related_sku DESC');
```

More information: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Hope can help you.

Comment: Fixed it for me, because i was using it like `->order('related_sku', 'desc');`

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the other answers here, `$kitCollection->getSelect()->order('column DESC')` works fine, but you can't add more than one column. For instance, `$kitCollection->getSelect()->order('column DESC, column2 ASC')` will error. This is because of the work that Magento does to escape the column names. To get around this, you can use a `Zend_Db_Expr` like so:

```
$kitCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('related_sku DESC, column2 ASC'));
```

Answer (score 1):

easymoden00b,`setOrder()` is not working due Eav structure on product.As @Sande say  to use `addAttributeToSort()`function,because of

- `Magento is join multiple tables  for product collection.`
- `Attribute alias name at collection`
- `setOrder() function` is working when it `order expression`
  **Fieldname,SortOrder** is `correct`.

You can see,how magento is create field alias and it relate eav table attribute at class  [Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract](http://freegento.com/doc/d3/d1b/class_mage___eav___model___entity___collection___abstract.html#947e55f60c43b5594b63755a3740c933)

```
public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
{
    if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
        $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute).' '.$dir);
        return $this;
    }
    if (isset($this->_staticFields[$attribute])) {
        $this->getSelect()->order("e.{$attribute} {$dir}");
        return $this;
    }
    if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attribute])) {
        $attrInstance = $this->_joinAttributes[$attribute]['attribute'];
        $entityField = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attribute) . '.' . $attrInstance->getAttributeCode();
    } else {
        $attrInstance = $this->getEntity()->getAttribute($attribute);
        $entityField = 'e.' . $attribute;
    }

    if ($attrInstance) {
        if ($attrInstance->getBackend()->isStatic()) {
            $orderExpr = $entityField;
        } else {
            $this->_addAttributeJoin($attribute, 'left');
            if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attribute])||isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
                $orderExpr = $attribute;
            } else {
                $orderExpr = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attribute).'.value';
            }
        }

        if (in_array($attrInstance->getFrontendClass(), $this->_castToIntMap)) {
            $orderExpr = Mage::getResourceHelper('eav')->getCastToIntExpression(
                $this->_prepareOrderExpression($orderExpr)
            );
        }

        $orderExpr .= ' ' . $dir;
        $this->getSelect()->order($orderExpr);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for sorting the order of options in a configurable product's attribute. Start by copying Collection.php,

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/Collection.php`.

Then you can find this code:

```
foreach ($this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(array($productAttribute->getAttributeCode()), $this->getProduct()) as $associatedProduct) {
```

And replace it with this code:

```
$assProds = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(array($productAttribute->getAttributeCode()), $this->getProduct());
sort($assProds);
foreach ($assProds as $associatedProduct) {
```

This will allow you to sort the drop-down list of attribute options to alphabetical.  You can also reverse the order by using `array_reverse()` or similar functions.

Previously, my attribute options were in reverse alphabetical order.  Now, they're in alphabetical order.