# Set order for product Collection in magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, addattributetofilter

I am filtering product collection like below.

```
    $productSkuString = 'O, C, D, A, F, S';
        $productSkus = explode(', ', $productSkuString); 
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'sku', array('in' => $productSkus)
        )           
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->load();
        return $collection;
```

The above code filtering the product collection with mentioned skus. but not in the same order of the sku.

I need to load the product with same order where the sku is mentioned.

Currently its loading the product in random order.

Can anyone look into it and update me please

Comment: I found your issue. Please remove space from string. Add like this and then, check it. $productSkuString = 'O,C,D,A,F,S';
  $productSkus = explode(',', $productSkuString);

Comment: @RohanHapani, please update me full code, again its made me confused. please update me working code

Comment: Check chat room please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **setOrder** as below to sort product collection

```
 $productSkuString = 'O, C, D, A, F, S';
 $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'sku', array('in' => $productSkus)
        )           
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->setOrder(new Zend_Db_Expr("FIND_IN_SET('sku', ".$productSkuString.") ASC"))
        ->load();
```

**Reference:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3265557/10540508

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/137522/75828

Comment: tried this code, no change in it, I need to display in this order O, C, D, A, F, S

Comment: Ok.. got your point. I edited my code. Try that

Comment: not working again

Comment: You need to use ````Zend_Db_Expr````

Comment: Not working after that aslo

Comment: Please update me the answer

Comment: what error do you get after this code?

Comment: just error page, not found any error

Comment: try printing query ````echo $collection->getSelect(); ```` to find issue

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$productSkus = array("O","C","D","A");
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'sku', array('in' => $productSkus)
        )           
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->setOrder('sku','ASC')
        ->load();
```