# Magento2: Product collection multiple attribute filter issue

Tags: magento2

I need to get a product collection to filter multiple attributes.

Forexample:

**First:** color multi select filter(attribute) values: 23, 25, 26.

**Second:** system multi-select filter(attribute) values: 27, 28.

I am getting filter values in one array and need to filter in the collection.

There are comma separated `$list = 23, 25, 26,27, 28`
    In the controller file:

```
$list =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('list', false);
$filter_ids = explode(",",$list);

$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$categoryProducts = $productcollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('in',$filter_ids))->addAttributeToFilter('system', array('in',$filter_ids))->load();
```

I am not getting a result in this way.
where I am wrong. Please suggest to me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the result for only one product ? or is there any error?

Comment: I am getting zero result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with my code,

```
$list =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('list', false);
$filter_ids = explode(",",$list);
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$categoryProducts =  $productcollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=> 'color','in' => $filter_ids),
            array('attribute'=> 'system','in' => $filter_ids),
        )
    );
```

Comment: okay.. Am checking

Comment: Getting error
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal string offset 'attribute' in /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php on line 370

Comment: I have update the code, Need to use addAttributeToFilter instead of addFieldToFilter

Comment: Getting same error

Comment: @aravid are you checking?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! Its working for me

Comment: @aravindI need to also add sort in this collection
added 
$productcollection->addAttributeToSort('product_title', $sort); But its not working

Comment: Flat category enabled or not ? You can check this in admin panel Stores > Settings > Configuration. Expand Catalog > Catalog > expand Storefront tab check whether Use Flat Catalog Product -> yes/no

Comment: you can check this answer based on the configuration set, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62043/magento-unable-to-set-order-of-collection/62044#answer-62044

Comment: Also check whether for that attribute "Used in product listing" is Yes in backend